# add buttons pause stop rec with opencv and gtk

Tags: python, opencv, gtk, pygtk

Hello everyone I need your help for a problem that comes up I have the following code where my webcam is activated and starts recording without any problem.

But I need to create three bots of Record, Pause and Stop, with gtk, but I do not know how I can do it with the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import gtk



def show_webcam(mirror=False):


    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    frame_width = int(cam.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cam.get(4))


    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S") + ".avi"
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,fourcc, 30, (frame_width,frame_height))

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        while True:
            ret_val, img = cam.read()
            if mirror: 
                img = cv2.flip(img, 1)

            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)
            out.write(img)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
                break  # esc to quit
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        pass

    cam.release()        
    out.release()        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm waiting for your help because it's for a project and nothing has been achieved

I managed to use the keyboard to pause the video and continue the recording, in addition to informing the user with visual cues, but I have not managed to create these actions by means of bonuses, using gtk so that the end user can record without problem. help

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import gtk
import keyboard
flagrecord=True


def show_webcam(flagrecord):

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    frame_width = int(cam.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cam.get(4))
    FONT = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S") + ".avi"

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,fourcc, 30, (frame_width,frame_height))

    while True:
        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        title = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d*%H:%M:%S")
        if flagrecord: 
            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "REC", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (0,0,255), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (0,0,255), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (30,430),(600,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, title, (40,470), FONT, 3 , (255,255,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)
            out.write(img)
        else:
            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "PAUSE", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (255,0,0), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (255,0,0), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (50,430),(570,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, "Audiencias En Pausa", (60,470), FONT, 3 , (255,255,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
            break  
        if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
            flagrecord=False
        if keyboard.is_pressed('c'):
            flagrecord=True 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            break     

    cam.release()        
    out.release()        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    show_webcam(mirror=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cv2.waitKey instead Keyboard lib. You can do this changes:

```
        q = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if q == 27: 
            break  
        if q == ord('p'):
            flagrecord=False
        if q == ord('c'):
            flagrecord=True 
        if q == ord('q'):
            break
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, I do it for tests but my wish is to create the buttons with gtk so that the suario clicks with the mouse and pause to record or stop the recording

I explain is to create a window with gtk in which are the three buttons pause stop and record for easier handling of the user since at this time it does with the keyboard which is not very comfortable